# Sencha Touch Lists height stretch to 100%

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have a vbox layout for my parent container and have 3 items, one with static data and two other lists.  I would like my lists' heights expand to 100% of the size of the content inside of them and I have an example of this [here](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#MfLkR#O5P4M).

As you can see, this works great when you have the data right there and ready to serve up, but in my case, I need to fetch the data for the two lists in the callback and set the respective store for each list. The problem is if I don't specify a height, the lists will be collapsed and will show no list data.  I've tried 'fit' and to refresh() the view in the callback but nothing seems to work.  Any ideas?

This is my method in the controller to fill the stores:

```js
function buildOrgView (record, view) {
    var managerUid = record.get('managerUid');
    var uid = record.get('uid');
    //Get data for org view
    if (managerUid) {
        var managerStore = new People.store.EmployeeDetails();//Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('mgrDetailsStore');
        managerStore.getProxy().setUrl(People.app.userDetailsUrl + managerUid);
        managerStore.load({
            callback: function (records) {
                var peerStore = new People.store.OrgMembers();
                peerStore.getProxy().setUrl(People.app.orgMembersUrl + managerUid);
                peerStore.load({
                    callback: function (recs) {
                        Ext.each(recs, function(item, idx, allItems) {
                           if (item.get('fullName') == record.get('fullName')) {
                               peerStore.remove(item);
                           }
                        });
                        view.getPeersList().setStore(peerStore);

                        var drStore = new People.store.OrgMembers();
                        drStore.getProxy().setUrl(People.app.orgMembersUrl + uid);
                        drStore.load({
                            callback: function (recs) {
                                view.getDirectReportsList().setStore(drStore);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is the List component I'd like to populate:

```js
Ext.define('People.view.people.OrgList', {
    extend: 'Ext.List',
    xtype: 'orgList',
    config: {
        cls: 'peopleInfo',
        store: 'OrgMembers',
//        scrollable: true,
//        height: 300,
        itemTpl: [
            "<div class='listView small'>",
            "   <tpl if='workforceID != undefined'>",
            "       <tpl if='workforceID == \"phind\"'>",
            "           <div class='avatar notFound user'></div>",
            "       <tpl else>",
            "           <div class='avatar'></div>",
            "       </tpl>",
            "   </tpl>",
            "   <ul class='data'>",
            "      <li><h3>{fullName}</h3></li>",
            "   </ul>",
            "</div>"
        ],
        listeners: [
            {
                fn: 'onPersonTap',
                event: 'itemtap'
            }
        ]
    },
    onPersonTap: function (dataview, newValue, oldValue, eOpts) {
        debugger;
        this.fireEvent('persontap', this, newValue, oldValue, eOpts);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way I found to resolve this issue was to multiple the number of elements in the list by the height of each element as I have defined in config and then add the height of the header (in my case 27px).  That yields the desired effect although, it's a bit hacky (fit layout should've really worked).

```js
view.getPeersList().setHeight(recs.length*50 + 27);
```

I was able to fix the heights of the items using these two params in Sencha Touch 2.1.1:

```js
itemHeight: 50,
variableHeights: false,
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set min height of list after setting store like this:

```js
list.setMinHeight(Ext.Viewport.getWindowHeight()/2);
```

or you can do this in `initialize` function of list view.

Comment: This looks promising as I see the actual container grow now, but the store is no longer populating it with data.  I used the initialize option.  Any ideas?

Comment: use DOM insoector and confirm if data is not filled or the list with data is collapsed and only container got the height not list.

Comment: Yeah, I looked at that but no records are in the list.  I'm not sure why add the height makes the records appear but it does; without it, I get no records.